# User timeout in Safari on iPad

Tags: php, javascript, ipad, timeout, logout

I'm creating a web app to be used on iPad. An important feature is that a user can only log in once and on one device at a time. I've already achieved this by updating a field in our database from 0 to 1 if the user logs in.

However it is also important to have a timeout feature in case the user forgets to logout. I tried doing this in PHP but it wasn't appropriate because the page would have to be refreshed before the script would run to log the user out.

So then I tried doing it client side with JavaScript (a simple page redirect after 30 minutes) but I've just learned that if you minimize Safari on the iPad all running scripts are halted so a user can easily click the home screen without logging out and the timeout wouldn't work.

Sooo...I'm out of ideas...is there any way to timeout a person in Safari on the iPad?

Comment: Generally it's not possible to detect with 100% accuracy when the user does leave; specially if you store session data in a database you will need to write a script that is being run periodically (ie a cronjob) and checks whether the sessions have expired or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your servers CRONJOB functionality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron and write a script for DB wide logout checking. This way you would completely take the user client out of the question, all you would have to do is monitor users actions with a timestamps which you would later check with your script.

For example, if you'd have field in your user table `last_action_time`, that you would update every time your site is reloaded or any other action is done. Just store `time()` into that field. And for the cronjob script, just check all the users with `last_action_time` < time()-(60*30) and update their field from 1 to 0 if that's the case.

Comment: +1. Don't trust the client. Just make sure you're also doing security checks at the beginning of each response. If the login has timed out, you can redirect subsequent requests to the authentication screen.